# syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, function, syntax-error

I have one error but don't know how to resolve.

```
syntax error, unexpected '='
```

my function

```
function getPageId($pageSlug) {
        "$". $pageSlug . "_slug" = $pageSlug;
        "$". $pageSlug . "page" = get_page_by_path("$". $pageSlug ."_slug");
        "$". $pageSlug . "images" = get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . "$". $pageSlug . "page"->ID);
    }
```

function call

```
getPageId("slider");
```

the code that i want rewrite by function

```
$page_slug ='slider';
$page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
$images = get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $page->ID);
```

please help to resolve this error
Thank you.

Comment: replace = to .= every where?

Comment: what is "page" here?

Comment: `${$pageSlug . "_slug"}` that's how you create dynamic variable names.

Comment: yes it's my dynamic variable

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

You want to refer about referencing variable from variable. Follow Dan Lee's suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *absolutely must use* dynamic variables (or [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)) names you can create them like this:

```
function getPageId($pageSlug) {
        ${$pageSlug . "_slug"} = $pageSlug;
        ${$pageSlug . "page"} = get_page_by_path(${$pageSlug ."_slug"});
        ${$pageSlug . "images"} = get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . ${$pageSlug . "page"}->ID);
}
```

But I consider it as bad practice and it should be avoided, as dynamic variable names tend to create chaos and are difficult to debug. Rather choose arrays.

Comment: Must this `${$pageSlug . "_slug"}` not be `${pageSlug . "_slug"}` ? In fact the second one is working, [demo](https://eval.in/309889)

Comment: thanks for your answers I know about that but I just start learning php this is first steps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
You have to change '=' to '.='
    function getPageId($pageSlug) {
            "$". $pageSlug . "_slug".= $pageSlug;
            "$". $pageSlug . "page".= get_page_by_path("$". $pageSlug ."_slug");
            "$". $pageSlug . "images".= get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . "$". $pageSlug . "page"->ID);
        }
```

Comment: same error

 syntax error, unexpected '.=' (T_CONCAT_EQUAL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gawatt\wp-content\themes\gawatt\home.php on line 13

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
function getPageId($pageSlug) {
        "$". $pageSlug . "_slug" = $pageSlug;
        "$". $pageSlug . "page" = get_page_by_path("$". $pageSlug ."_slug");
        "$". $pageSlug . "images" = get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . "$". $pageSlug . "page"->ID);
    }
```

with

```
function getPageId($pageSlug) {
        "$". $pageSlug . "_slug". = $pageSlug;
        "$". $pageSlug . "page". = get_page_by_path("$". $pageSlug ."_slug");
        "$". $pageSlug . "images". = get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='. "$". $pageSlug . "page"->ID);
    }
```

Comment: put what you want , you can't get ID from string "page" like this "page"->ID

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
function getPageId($pageSlug) {
    "$". $pageSlug . "_slug" = $pageSlug;
    "$". $pageSlug . "page" = get_page_by_path("$". $pageSlug ."_slug");
    "$". $pageSlug . "images" = get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . "$". $pageSlug . $page->ID);
}
```

Comment: Despite that you changed `'page'->ID` to `$page->ID`, to rest of the code will not work